# Why I get error on if statement which is use Boolean method?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have this function that returns a boolean value:

```
fun isSutableData(isAmount: Boolean, Value: String): Boolean {
    val customValue = Value.replace(".", "").toLong()
    val dataOverBase: Long

    if (isAmount) 
        dataOverBase = (customValue * 100) / (baseAmount?.value ?: 1)
    else 
        dataOverBase = customValue

    return data in 1..dataOverBase
}
```

here how I use isSutableData function:

```
 val isTiptooBig = isSutableData(isAmount, value)
```

and if statement:

```
   if(isTiptooBig){
        //some logic
     }
```

on the if statement I get s error:

```
     Type mismatch: inferred type is Boolean? but Boolean was expected
```

While I change if statement to this:

```
   if(isTiptooBig == true){
        //some logic
     }
```

The error disappears.

Why do I get this error if isSutableData returns Boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> inferred type is `Boolean?`

This means that Kotlin believes that the `isTiptooBig` expression is of type `Boolean?`. Note the question mark. It's important. That means the value is one of **3** things:

- `true`
- `false`
- `null`

And given that it's 3 things and not 2 things, `if (that)` isn't allowed. However, `if (that == true)` is (it would mean the `if` block is *not* executed if `that` is `false` or `null`; only if `that` is `true` does it execute.

Now, *why* does kotlin think that? I don't know - from what you pasted, it wouldn't think that. There must be more going on.

Answer (score 0):

> inferred type is Boolean?

`Boolean` and `Boolean?` are different. `Boolean?` means it will have an additional type i.e null other than true or false in this case.

Also, while you are returning i guess you are returning a range not boolean value. So, check the code once for that . It may solve the issue